# Jquery prepend() adding extra unwanted tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cordova, windows-8.1

I am trying to prepend html element into div in windows 8.1 phonegap application but its giving some weird output. Please see below code which I am using to prepend element.

```
var wrapper = $('.list');
wrapper.prepend("<div> Hello </div>");
```

It should give output like this

```
<div class="list">
   <div> Hello </div>
</div>
```

But giving some weird output

```
<div class="list">
  <head></head>
  <body onload="startExec()">
    <div> Hello </div>
  </body>
</div>
```

Please get back on this as soon as possible.

**Update**

I am adding JavaScript Dynamic Content shim for Windows Store apps i.e winstore-jscompat. Is this issue coming because of shim?

Answer (score 0):

Try This one

```
$('div.list').prepend("<div> Hello </div>");
```

Answer (score 0):

I Know this is a bit late - but better late than never :)

You have pointed out the issue your self: The cause is winstore-jscompat.

Get the latest version that fixes this issue here: https://github.com/MSOpenTech/winstore-jscompat

I had this issue my self, and just verified that the newest version fixes it.